# Pip install error (Pyside to Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, pip, pyside

I'm trying to `pip install pyside` to my Raspberry Pi and receive the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo pip install pyside
Collecting pyside
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/ac/ca31db6f2225844d37a41b10615c3d371587677efd074db29855e7035de6/PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyside
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyside ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-TXwQwt/pyside/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmps80BMupip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  Removing /tmp/pip-build-TXwQwt/pyside/pyside_package
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Python architecture is 32bit
  error: Failed to find cmake. Please specify the path to cmake with --cmake parameter.

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyside
  Running setup.py clean for pyside
Failed to build pyside
Installing collected packages: pyside
  Running setup.py install for pyside ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-TXwQwt/pyside/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5BdNE7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Removing /tmp/pip-build-TXwQwt/pyside/pyside_package
    running install
    running build
    Python architecture is 32bit
    error: Failed to find cmake. Please specify the path to cmake with --cmake parameter.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-TXwQwt/pyside/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5BdNE7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-TXwQwt/pyside/
pi@raspberrypi:/ $
```

I've tried fixing it with `sudo pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade`, `sudo apt install -y libmysqlclient-dev`, `python setup.py install`, and `sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools` but none have worked to allow me to install Pyside. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

I'm running Raspbian Stretch on a raspberry pi 3 if that matters.

Comment: `Failed to find cmake` - do you have it installed? `which cmake`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [precompiled wheels](https://www.piwheels.org/project/PySide/) from https://www.piwheels.org/

There are no pyside binary wheels for Pi so you need to install a lot of [prerequisites](https://pyside.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building/linux.html) and compiles from sources:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git cmake libqt4-dev libphonon-dev python2.7-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev qtmobility-dev libqtwebkit-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

which python version you are using, since this module supports only below listed version.

```
[(2.6), (2.7), (3.2), (3.3), (3.4)]
```

Comment: I'm trying to install it to 2.7 (which I have 2.7.13) but it is worth noting that I also have 3.5 installed (which is commanded by `pip-3.2` rather than `pip` on my system)

Comment: Sorry I ran it again and I think I was installing to the wrong python. I updated the error I receive when installing to Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

It looks self explanatory.

You are installing  the module on an unsupported version of python.

try installing with `pip2 install pyside`

Comment: sorry I'd accidentally copied the wrong error message. I've just updated it. I'm installing to Python 2.7